# I would like know why "&" came after "FrontEndToken["New"] here

Tags: syntax

I am a newbie to this Mathematica world who lives in South Korea, which is
not a desirable place to have people to discuss Mathematica.
So I came here, even though this question may look very simple or stupid,
only way to get to solve this has been to ask you here.
I have been very thankful and will be for your advice and sharing.

The question is this.
Sometimes there are several of & in Mathematica code.
Sometimes I know the role of it.
But sometimes I don't.
Below is the case I can not know even after thinking really hard.

Would you teach me with this?

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[
   ButtonBox["new", ButtonFunction -> (FrontEndToken["New"] &)]], 
  "Text"]]
```

Comment: It's a "constant function"; as a simpler example, `0 &` is a function that will return `0` for any argument.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this topic, and especially at this answer: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478)

Comment: Thank you very much, J.M and Kuba!